# How to enable short tags in IIS 7.5

Tags: php, iis-7, php-shorttags

I have edited the php.ini file, but it is still not being enabled:

```
       short_open_tag
     Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On
```

says it is off in the phpinfo file.

I am using php 5.3

cheers.

This is how you fix it:

If you go to PHP Manager, then go under "manage all settings" which is under "PHP settings", you can enable it via a UI. Frustrating!

Comment: Is this the exact exerpt from your `php.ini` file?

Comment: yes. I uncommented out short_open_Tag and default_value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For ISS you need to go to "**PHP Manager**"
Then look for "**Manage all settings**"

Then search for **short_open_tag** 
Double click on it and give value On

[image]

Follow the gif file

Restart the ISS and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You should not uncomment the `Default Value` bit. The way it should look in php.ini is:

```
short_open_tag = On
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On
```

The fact that there was no valid assignment must have set it to Off.

Make sure you restart your server for the changes to be applied.

Comment: Are you sure there's nothing else in the way disabling it? A `.htaccess` file?

Comment: hmm using IIS 7, dont think there is one.

Comment: Ok, another idea - are you sure the `php.ini` you're editing is actually read by the server? Try changing any other setting, restart and see if it was applied.

Comment: Fixed it. Basically if you go to PHP Manager, then go under "manage all settings" which is under "PHP settings", you can enable it via a UI. Frustrating!

Comment: What's bizarre is that if you enable it via the .ini file, there are 2 short_open_tag entries when you go to all settings, and the 2nd one is set to off. Go Windows!

Answer (score 1):

php.ini includes this tag twice; once in Quick Reference and once in Language Options.  Aside from being confusing, the Language Options copy is set to Off so any change that you make to the Quick Reference entry will be overridden.

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Quick Reference ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
...
; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off
```

and once in

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Language Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
...
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag = Off
```

My advice is to leave the Quick Reference copy commented out and change the Language Options copy to On.

```
short_open_tag = On
```